# Microsoft/Azure logout doesn't redirect to back to my app

Tags: android, azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, appauth

I have a simple Azure app registration and I have an android app where I use [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) to implement OAuth Microsoft/Azure login. Login works fine, I get the access token. Redirect from chrome tab back to app works fine. What doesn't work is the logout. I'm not redirected back to the app. Is the user supposed to close chrome tab himself?

**Demo**

https://i.ibb.co/1JFyYQ5/Hnet-image-3.gif

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.9.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.9.0'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#D22B2B"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Base64
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import net.openid.appauth.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AuthorizationService.TokenResponseCallback {

    private val authorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/5445bade-1c6c-45cf-b87a-f21276046af6/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
    private val tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/5445bade-1c6c-45cf-b87a-f21276046af6/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    private val endSessionEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout"
    private val clientId = "041cb3c5-8096-454a-b3c2-c18bb783cde0"
    private val clientSecret = ""
    private val redirectUrl = "oauth.playground://callback"
    private val scope = "openid"

    private val authorizationServiceConfig = AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
        Uri.parse(authorizationEndpoint),
        Uri.parse(tokenEndpoint),
        null,
        Uri.parse(endSessionEndpoint)
    )

    private lateinit var authService: AuthorizationService

    private val authState = AuthState()

    private val RC_LOGIN = 1
    private val RC_LOGOUT = 2

    private lateinit var textEmail: TextView
    private lateinit var progress: View
    private lateinit var btnLogin: View
    private lateinit var btnLogout: View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textEmail = findViewById(R.id.text_email)
        progress = findViewById(R.id.progress)
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login)
        btnLogout = findViewById(R.id.btn_logout)

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener { login() }
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener { logout() }

        authService = AuthorizationService(this)
    }

    private fun login() {
        val authRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder(authorizationServiceConfig, clientId, ResponseTypeValues.CODE, Uri.parse(redirectUrl))
            .setScope(scope)
            .setPrompt(AuthorizationRequest.Prompt.LOGIN)
            .build()

        try {
            val authIntent: Intent = authService.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(authRequest)
            startActivityForResult(authIntent, RC_LOGIN)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No suitable browser is available to perform the authorization flow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun logout() {
        val endSessionRequest = EndSessionRequest.Builder(authState.authorizationServiceConfiguration!!)
            .setIdTokenHint(authState.idToken)
            .setPostLogoutRedirectUri(Uri.parse(redirectUrl))
            .build()
        val endSessionIntent: Intent = authService.getEndSessionRequestIntent(endSessionRequest)
        startActivityForResult(endSessionIntent, RC_LOGOUT)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            RC_LOGIN -> {
                if (data != null) {
                    val response = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(data)
                    val exception = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(data)

                    if (response != null) {
                        authState.update(response, exception)
                        progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        authService.performTokenRequest(response.createTokenExchangeRequest(), ClientSecretPost(clientSecret), this)
                    }
                }
            }
            RC_LOGOUT -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    textEmail.text = null
                    btnLogin.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    btnLogout.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Logout successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTokenRequestCompleted(response: TokenResponse?, exception: AuthorizationException?) {
        progress.visibility = View.GONE

        if (response != null) {
            authState.update(response, exception)
            val idToken = parseJwtToken(authState.accessToken!!)
            textEmail.text = idToken.uniqueName
            btnLogin.visibility = View.GONE
            btnLogout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun parseJwtToken(jwtIdToken: String): JwtPaylod {
        val payload = jwtIdToken.split('.')[1]
        val payloadJson = String(Base64.decode(payload, Base64.NO_WRAP))
        return Gson().fromJson(payloadJson, JwtPaylod::class.java)
    }

    private data class JwtPaylod(
        @SerializedName("unique_name") val uniqueName: String?
    )

}
```

**Azure app registration**
[image]

Comment: Did you solved this? if yes, please share your answer

Comment: @Moorthy I gave up looking for solution. That's why I hope someone in here can help me out.

Comment: @Moorthy if you find an answer to this, please also share. Thank you.

Comment: Did any of you guys get any solution on same ?